# Is there a kanji for "hacker"?

Tags: kanji

As I understand it, most foreign words in Japanese are written in Katakana. However, I am curious as to whether in contemporary written Japanese, hacker is written as a literal adaptation of the western word, or whether a idiomatically Japanese character/concept is substituted in its place.

For the purposes of this discussion, what I mean by hacker is "Person who attempts to subvert the security of digital systems" rather than the wider meaning of the term.

Is this even a concept in contemporary Japanese outside of its status as foreign word?

Comment: I'm certain that's not what your talking about, but if you really want *kanji*, [look no further than Chinese](http://www.geocities.co.jp/SilkRoad-Lake/4199/library/heiker.html): 黒客【ハッカー】, and 中国黒客連盟 (＝Hacker Union Of China).

Comment: Why wouldn't I be looking for kanji?

Comment: Using these kanji in the context of Japanese falls under the category of very creative writing; ie. you wouldn't use them normally. Like 吐露非狩古鬱【トロピカルフルーツ】

Comment: [Tag `ハッカー` on *chiebukuro*, with many questions.](http://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/tag/tags.php?page=1&tag=ハッカー)

Comment: [墓]{ハッカー}. Just joking...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**ハッカー** is widely recognized by the general population in the *narrow* sense OP indicated. But if you use this in, say, [Japanese Stack Overflow](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/), it will soon be corrected. "Hey, don't use ハッカー in that way! [They're not criminals](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8F%E3%83%83%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC)!"

**クラッカー** specifically refers to the evil ones, and is preferred by IT professionals.

That said, both ハッカー and クラッカー are still a bit slangy terms in Japanese. Although newspapers seem to use ハッカー freely recently, official government documents still avoid using them. For example, [Information-technology Promotion Agency](http://www.ipa.go.jp/), which is a semi-official organization, does not use ハッカー/クラッカー, and uses other lengthy replacements like **攻撃者、侵入者、悪意のある第三者、悪意のある人……** in its [security guidelines](http://www.ipa.go.jp/security/vuln/websecurity.html).

I don't know why you need a kanji version, but hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for the referral for 攻撃者 (~attacker) etc. If you prefer Kanji versions because they may sound more formal and/or professional, these expressions are what you're looking for.

Comment: On a side note, it seems that words such as "attacker" or "intruder" are common in English papers as well. And: "The Information Assurance mission confronts the formidable challenge of preventing **foreign adversaries** from gaining access to sensitive or classified national security information."

Answer (score 3):

No. There isn't a single kanji nor a compound which means "hacker". Jisho.org returns no results when searching [kanji](http://beta.jisho.org/search/hacker%20%23kanji), and only words containing ハッカー when searching [words](http://beta.jisho.org/search/hacker). People would just rather write new terms in katakana than to create a new kanji for them.

However, as blutorange stated, the Chinese word for it is 黒客 (pronounced hēikè), but of course, that's Chinese and not Japanese.

Comment: The Chinese term should be either 黑客 (Note the difference between Japanese and Chinese typography) or 駭客.