# What is the Japanese word for a 3D character artist/modeller?

Tags: word-requests, english-to-japanese, anime

If I were looking for a Japanese manga artist, I would use the Japanese characters for the word "mangaka." I need the Japanese word and characters for a word that means "3D character artist" or "3D character modeller."

Do the Japanese have a specific term for this, like mangaka is for 2D art? Or do they just use the same words except in Japanese?

I'm trying to find a Japanese 3D character modeller. My own Japanese is actually very fluent, I just need to know if there is a specific term for it or some other way to help me find one. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The translations are 3Dキャラクターアーティスト and 3Dキャラクターモデラー, respectively. 3D is usually pronounced スリーディー.

Unlike 漫画家, there are no common kanji Japanese words for these. Here's why: [Why is a blackboard called 黒板, but a whiteboard is not called 白板?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/63072/5010)

Comment: Sculptors use the word 塑造 for (clay) modelling, but as far as I know, it's never used in 3DCG contexts.